# Using str_extract with perl to extract substrings

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I am try to use perl with stringr to get the characters in a between two words but the example I was given does not work and give the following error message:

```
x = "PRODUCT colgate good but not good OKAY"
library(stringr)
str_extract(string = x, pattern = perl("(?<=PRODUCT).*(?=OKAY)"))
```

> Error in perl("(?<=PRODUCT).*(?=OKAY)") : could not find function "perl"

I am expecting the outcome to be :
"colgate good but not good "

Comment: Looks like `perl()` was removed from `stringr` as of v. 1.3.0: [see here](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#stringr-1-3-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need any `perl` wrapping (using `stringr` version -`‘1.4.0’`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string = x, pattern = "(?<=PRODUCT ).*(?= OKAY)")
#[1] "colgate good but not good"
```

Comment: Thank you not responding RFD. This solved it. Now it is back to the documentation to understand what else has been improved.